# Not possible to pass WixBundleProviderKey variable to msipackage

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have a problem with the burn built-in variable WixBundleProviderKey. I need to pass the value of this variable to an msi package. My problem is that the value of this variable is not evaluated, and the msi will only receive an empty string. I have tested with other built in variable and it works as expected.

Any ideas why this is not working? Is there a workaround?

Example:

```
<Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="Test" >
        <MsiPackage Id="Test" 
            DisplayName="Test 4.10.0002"
            DisplayInternalUI="no"
            Visible="no"
            SourceFile=".\Template\ProductsToInstall\Test\Test 4.10.msi"
            Name="Test\Test 4.10.msi"
            Cache="yes"
            CacheId="Test 4.10"
            Compressed="no"
            Vital="yes"
            Permanent="no">

            <MsiProperty Name="BURN_WIXBUNDLEORIGINALSOURCE" Value="[WixBundleOriginalSource]" />
            <MsiProperty Name="BURN_COMMONAPPDATAFOLDER" Value="[CommonAppDataFolder]" />
            <MsiProperty Name="BURN_WIXBUNDLEPROVIDERKEY" Value="[WixBundleProviderKey]" />
        </MsiPackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that should be fixed in v3.10: http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4630/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to the question, but maybe it helps.
In my case I needed to pass the value of *WixBundleProviderKey* variable to msi to get the full path to my BundeSetup.exe, which is cached in *"CommonAppDataFolder\Package Cache\WixBundleProviderKey"* directory. To do that I created a property with *FileSearch* element in msi, providing to the full path of the searching file.

```
<Property Id="BUNDLECACHEPATH">
  <DirectorySearch Id="BundleDirSearch" Path="[CommonAppDataFolder]Package Cache" Depth="1">
    <FileSearch Name="BundleSetup.exe" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

Comment: Not much efficient solution, 'cause the user can change the name of BundeSetup.exe before running it. See my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick.
You can create new variable with name "BUNDLE_KEY" (for example)

```
<Variable Name="BUNDLE_KEY" Type="string" Value="[WixBundleProviderKey]" />
```

And then apply this variable to MsiProperty:

```
 <MsiProperty Name="YOU_PROPERTY_IN_MSI" Value="[BUNDLE_KEY]" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only way to pass *WixBundleProviderKey* value in Standard Bootstrapper Application is to pass it through *InstallFolder* variable:

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Value="[WixBundleProviderKey]" />
```

The other solution is to pass it inside the path to the bundle setup temp files through *DirectorySearch* element variable:

```
<util:DirectorySearch Path="[TempFolder][WixBundleProviderKey]" Variable="KeyPath" />

<MsiProperty Name="BUNDLE_KEY" Value="[KeyPath]" />
```

The way to get *WixBundleProviderKey* in your msi from [BUNDE_KEY] property value is to implement *C# Custom Action* using *String.Substring()* method. And put it inside *InstallUISequence* before *AppSearch* event - if you want to use the obtained value inside *RegistrySearch* element.